# Hangfire Register IoC Dependency in Scope For Job at Run Time

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, hangfire, hangfire-autofac

**Issue**: most jobs are dependent on configuration dependency.

**Ideal Solution**: (copied here and at end just to save reading if you already know exactly how to do this)

I would like to

- during job Q (using filter or any other options) save some data (object / json / string)
- during job processing: intercept creation process of job and register dependency using stashed data to IoC container in scope for that job

**Old Solution**: for the custom "job scheduler" that I am replacing we take the following steps

- before resolving the job processor we crate a lifetime scope and using job data register the dependency with data provided
- then using "job type" resolve the job and process

**Hack Solution**: so this works for most but I still want to know how to accomplish what I am trying to do, by creating a "wrapper job" class that uses the same data to crate the same scope when running the job.

**Ideal Solution**: Ideally I can inject logic and

- during save stash needed data (plenty of ways to do this)
- during pre job processing access IoC to create the scope register this dependency

I have Tried / Looked Into Filter Attributes - works to save and restore data but have not found any access to IoC or lifetime scope here.

there were a few other options but they too were limited in "exposure" to the IoC container / scope

Ideal Solution:
I would like to

- during job Q (using filter or any other options) save some data (object / json / string)
- during job processing: intercept creation process of job and register dependency using stashed data to IoC container in scope for that job

Comment: You may give another chance to `Hangfire.Server.IServerFilter`
For my part, I create an  AsyncLocal scope object in `OnPerforming`, which I reset in `OnPerformed`. (My IoC is Ninject)

Comment: @jbl how are you getting a ref to the IoC container? Taking another look myself, thanks for the note!

Comment: I don't need to directly access the IoC. It is automatically used to instantiate my composition root (the generic argument of the `Enqueue` method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wow I am dense, so looking over the [Delegate Factories](Delegate Factories) documentation and taking a deeper dive into [Implicit Relationship Types](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html)

I realized I was making this a lot harder than it needed to be and what I was looking for is [clearly documented here](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#parameterized-instantiation-func-x-y-b) but I never looked close enough so here is a working sample

note:

1. not all dependencies are required at runtime, Autofac fills in everything not provided by the `func`
2. you do no need to configure or register anything special to create the Func<>, just add it to the constructor of your dependent class

#### Sample:

```
  public class ScratchPad
  {
      [Fact]
      public void WhenRunningThisThenItWorks()
      {
          var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
          builder.RegisterType<MyNeedyRuntimeClass>();
          builder.RegisterType<SomethingElseNeeded>();
          var container = builder.Build();

          var theFuncFactory = container.Resolve<Func<SomeRuntimeThing, MyNeedyRuntimeClass>>();
          var func = () => theFuncFactory.Invoke(new SomeRuntimeThing());
          func.Should().NotThrow("constructor need for `SomeRuntimeThing` should be passed in from Func and dependency for `SomethingElseNeeded` is handled from the service registration");
      }
  }
```

here are the empty classes I used just for ref

```
  class MyNeedyRuntimeClass
  {
      public MyNeedyRuntimeClass(SomeRuntimeThing someRuntimeIdOrSomething, SomethingElseNeeded bar)
      {
          //....
      }
  }

  internal class SomeRuntimeThing
  {
  }

  internal class SomethingElseNeeded
  {
  }
```